# Retrieving result set through a double-layer has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three models:

- User
- File
- Download

`User` has_many `Files`, `File` belongs_to `User`

`File` has_many `Downloads`, `Download` belongs_to `User`

Is there any way to retrieve all a `User`'s `Downloads`, without iterating through all `Files`, then retrieving the `Downloads` associated with each file? (this would generate lots of queries)

**EDIT**

I've found a way of loading a `User`, it's `Files` and `Downloads` in just 3 queries

```
user = User.includes(:uploads => [:downloads]).find(1)
```

However, what if I already have a `User` object?

And what if I just want to load the users downloads without loading their uploads? (using a join)

**EDIT**

```
Download.joins(:upload => :user).where(:users  => { :id => user.id })
```

Is there a way of doing this having the reference the users table primary key directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried

```
class User
  has_many :downloads, :through => :files
end
```